# Is there any appropriate way to break a specific S-BOX?

Tags: cryptanalysis

[image]

I have just started learning cryptography. And I came across such a question that had troubled me for several days.
The picture contains an LFSR and an S-Box. 
The LFSR is 32-bit long and the inside structure of the S-Box is unknown which means the whole system is keyed by the S-Box.
The round function picks four bits and looks them up in the S-Box, feed them back in the next four bits over and shifts circularly by four bits.

Now I put a 32-bit long plaintext into the LFSR and the LFSR starts moving.
After 8 clock ticks, it finishes a full-round encryption. To finish a whole process of encryption, it will go 8 full-round encryptions.
Now I can make an arbitrary number of requests in this system which means that I can put different 32-bit texts into the system and check their results after 8 full-round encryptions (= one whole encryption process).

I have several questions about how to know the exact content inside the S-Box:

1. I have learned several common attack ways to recover an S-Box like the Differentiable Cryptoanalysis and I am a little bit confused about the choice of different attack approaches. Can such ways apply on such a circumstance?
2. Does this problem have a special property that allows me to own a special-made way to break the S-Box?

Comment: This is the third time this question is asked. The first is got the comment and deleted by the OP!

Comment: I checked a lot of questions on this website and failed to find some similar questions to this breaking problem? Can you give me some possible insights in order to solve this quesiton?

Comment: Beacuse some of your friends asked and deleted!